# numbers of the nouns = the noun numbers?

Tags: ielts

1. The average **patient numbers** `at` Bangkok Hospitals this mouth *was* much higher . . .

2. The average **number of patients** `at` Bangkok Hospitals this mouth *was* much higher . . .

a. The average **patient numbers** `using` Bangkok Hospitals this mouth *was* much higher . . .

b. The average **number of patients** `using` Bangkok Hospitals this mouth *was* much higher . . .

**Which are better, 1. or 2. and a. or b.?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 and B.

- 1 is incorrect because the subject "patient numbers" (plural) disagrees with the verb "was" (singular). 2 is correct because the subject "**number** of patients" (singular) agrees with the verb (singular)
- A is incorrect because (patient) **numbers** cannot "use" Bangkok hospitals. B is correct because a (number of) **patients** can "use" Bangkok hospitals.

Comment: sorry I originally typed the ones that were incorrect (1 and A) but meant to type the ones that were correct (2 and B). I've corrected it

Comment: So, **"the/a number(s) of patients"** is considered **humans**, but **"patient number(s)"** is considered **figures**, right?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: @hbtpoprock *Patients* are people. And *patients using hospitals* are people. But numbers of anything, including patients who use hospitals, are figures. The sentence that's correct is parsed as *average number [a figure]* ***of*** *(patients [people] using Bangkok hospitals)*.

Comment: Ty @JasonBassford